# Changing CSS of last item in ul

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul style="padding-left:12px; float:right;">
  <li style="display:inline; padding-right:2px;">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline; padding-right:2px;">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline; padding-right:2px;">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline; padding-right:2px;">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline; padding-right:0px;">content</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to clean this up by using styles. However, the last li throws a wrench in things. It has a padding-right of 0 instead of 2. My challenge is, this HTML is being generated programmatically. Is there a way I can write my CSS to basically say use padding-right 2 for everything except for the last list item? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this. this is te way 

<ul id="nav">
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
</ul>


ul#nav {
      padding-left:12px; 
      float:right;
     }
ul#nav li{
        display:inline; 
        padding-right:2px;
     }
ul#nav li:last-child{
        padding-right:0px;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
li:not(:last-child) { padding-right:2px !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know how you're going to select this exact ul based on what you've posted, but this should work.

```
ul li:last-child {
    padding-right: 2px !important;
}
```

Comment: It won't work, because he has an inline style *padding-right:0px;* and it'll take priority over any stylesheet.

Comment: @todinov: you're wrong, this will work. The `!important` rule will overrule the inline style, check this demo I made: http://jsfiddle.net/hetcnk7y/1/

Comment: @stanze: I agree, it isn't good to use `!important`, but if you can't alter the HTML code, it's the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<ul style="padding-left:12px; float:right;" id="nav">
  <li style="display:inline; ">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline;">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline; ">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline; ">content</li>
  <li style="display:inline;">content</li>
</ul>
```

Then we can easily make the text of the last item red with:

```
ul#nav li:last-child {
   color: Red; 
   padding-right:0px;
}
ul#nav li:not(:last-child) { 
   padding-right:2px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul style="padding-left:12px; float:right;">
  <li >content</li>
  <li >content</li>
  <li >content</li>
  <li >content</li>
  <li >content</li>
</ul>

ul li{display:inline; padding-right:0px;}

ul li:last-child{padding-right:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is your solution:

**Ques.** How to cleanup and style listing except the last item using CSS?

**Ans.**

```
li {display:inline; padding-right:2px;}
li:last-child {padding-right:0;}
```

### In case, if wants to pick/ modify any specific child element as following:

** For only "first" child:**

```
li:first-child { //your css style here}
```

** For only "last" child:**

```
li:last-child { //your css style here}
```

** For any specific child use "nth-child" **

```
li:nth-child(1) { //your css style here}
li:nth-child(2) { //your css style here}
li:nth-child(3) { //your css style here}
li:nth-child(4) { //your css style here}
li:nth-child(5) { //your css style here}
```

Comment: Read the question carefully first